# using mllib in apache spark 2.0.2 and "The import org.apache.spark.mllib cannot be resolved" error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I just want to do some 2D Matrix operation in using JavaRDD and looked into this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html. I tried doing exactly the same sample codes that are given here. But eclipse doesn't seem to recognize the mllib in the first place. Here is my code snippet (same as that in the above link)

```
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils;
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix;
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrices;

    JavaRDD<Vector> rows = ... // a JavaRDD of local vectors
                           // Create a RowMatrix from an JavaRDD<Vector>.
    RowMatrix mat = new RowMatrix(rows.rdd());

    // Get its size.
    long m = mat.numRows();
    long n = mat.numCols();

    // QR decomposition 
    QRDecomposition<RowMatrix, Matrix> result = mat.tallSkinnyQR(true);
```

I am using Spark 2.0.2. Where am I going wrong? Do we need any maven dependency? I checked my spark home directory, and I have the mllib directory and mllib-local directory in my spark directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pom.xml to see if there is a spark-mllib dependency. If not, get the right version from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11

At the point of my answering, the latest version is:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your spark-mllib configuration in `pom.xml` hasn't been runtime.

Comment: Please give an example as to how we can achieve this.